# How to chek a path that contains parameters via request.path?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my `questions` app, the `url_patterns` in `models.py` is :

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('<int:question_id>/'     , views.question    , name='question'),
    path('new/'                   , views.new_question, name='newquestion'),    
    path('edit/<int:question_id>/', views.edit        , name='edit'),    
]
```

In my templates whenever I want to for example check if the `newquestion` url is loaded, I try this:

```
{% if 'questions/new' in request.path %}
    some code
{% endif %}
```

How to check if the `question` url is loaded when it contains an integer parameter - the `question_id` -

Comment: Most of the cases, the views render a *different* template, so you actually do not need this (often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this, you can use [**`request.resolver_match`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) to obtain the [**`ResolverMatch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch), and then obtain the [**`.view_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.view_name) to obtain the *name* of the `path`, `url` `re_path`, etc., so:

```
{% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'edit' %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

But that being said, often if your templates need to inspect that, you should use separate templates that do not need to check this, especially since the number of paths will grow, and eventually you will change paths, views, etc. By using different ones, you keep the impact small.